# CSS Transform: Scale misaligns overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, shadow

I've created a CSS ribbon with another CSS ribbon directly behind the first to serve as a shadow.

I'm trying to scale both of these together.

I wrapped the ribbons in a `div` and applied a `transform: scale` to this parent `div`. Instead of growing or shrinking the ribbons as expected, they became misaligned.

What is causing the ribbons to go out of alignment when `scale` is applied, and how can it be fixed?

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bookmark-container {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}
.bookmark,
.bookmark-shadow {
  border: 0.7em solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
}
.bookmark {
  color: #337ab7;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
.bookmark-shadow {
  border: 0.75em solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
  margin-left: -0.05em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fixed-header" style="background: #fefefe; height: 50px;">
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Unscaled: </div>
  <div>
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
    <div class="bookmark-shadow"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Scaled to 80%: </div>
  <div class="bookmark-container">
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
    <div class="bookmark-shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I fully understand that this is not an answer for your question, but maybe it would be better to use `filter: drop-shadow()` to reach the same effect?

Comment: @SergeyZdobnov That's fantastic! I had been trying `box-shadow` but it put a shadow around the entire rectangle of the ribbon instead of following its contours. `filter: drop-shadow()` is a _much_ simpler solution than overlaying ribbons.

Comment: they become misaligned because you're scaling the parent and one of it's children depends on it `top: 0.9em;` so that has to be scaled too which causes the misalignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Children

Change the size of the elements rather than the parent. This gives more accurate results.

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bookmark-container div {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.bookmark,
.bookmark-shadow {
  border: 0.7em solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
}

.bookmark {
  color: #337ab7;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bookmark-shadow {
  border: 0.75em solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
  margin-left: -0.05em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.9em;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fixed-header" style="background: #fefefe; height: 50px;">
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Unscaled: </div>
  <div>
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
    <div class="bookmark-shadow"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Scaled to 80%: </div>
  <div class="bookmark-container">
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
    <div class="bookmark-shadow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As a matter of fact, the elements here are not connected to the End-to-End. For this reason, it is possible to calculate `".7em"` value with `".75em"` value as `".05em"` mathematically. But when the dimensioning enters the work, the browsers will round off some of the values. That's why 0.05em in "Scale 100%", "scale 80%" is not calculated with the formula of `0.05 * 80/100`. Naturally, the growth or shrinkage rates of both individual elements do not fit exactly.

Unfortunately, browsers have such an ability. Because it is also possible to see the same in `SVG` formats. If the `point` is not connected to one another, the two "different" scales give different results.

### Another one: Limit by parent

In order to achieve an exact result, it would make more sense to use the elements in nested. `::before` `::after`
This returns you as an element for a "bookmark".

```css
.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.fixed-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bookmark-container {
  transform: scale(0.8);
}

.bookmark {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #337ab7;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.bookmark::before {
  content: "";
  color: #337ab7;
  box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  border: 0.7em solid;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bookmark::after {
  content: "";
  color: rgba(64, 64, 64, 0.5);
  border: 0.75em solid;
  box-shadow: 0 -1em;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container fixed-header" style="background: #fefefe; height: 50px;">
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Unscaled: </div>
  <div>
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 20px;">Scaled to 80%: </div>
  <div class="bookmark-container">
    <div class="bookmark"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I mentioned above, it seems as if there are two overlapping shadows. But this is only relevant to the browser. If you get too close, you actually get a smoother looks.

[image]